# Line number specific text-width setting

Tags: formatting

I use gvim for writing emails and use `tw=72` to break long lines. Now I also edit basic mail headers in the same document, e.g. I am adding recipients to my mail. Now with `tw=72` it also breaks every time after 72 characters.

How can I set `tw=0` on the first 4 lines (that's the header part), and `tw=72` for the rest of the document?

My formatoptions look like this, if that's relevant:

```
set fo+=tcqn
```

Comment: `textwidth` is applied to the whole buffer.

Comment: Also see: [Prevent Vim from breaking up links mid-tag in markdown](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/564/51). You could use a similar solution for emails, either by checking if `line('.') < 5`, or by checking if the line starts with an email header (e.g. `From: `, `To: `, etc.).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks a lot, this was the key to the solution. I added my full answer with the necessary modifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Carpetsmoker's comment on my question, I was able to solve this exactly like I wanted it to have.

With the following function in .vimrc (or in my case in a special file that it only loaded when editing my emails), tw is set to 500 if the line number is smaller than 5, otherwise it's 72. With `au CursorMovedI` this is checked everytime the cursor moves.

```
" Set tw to 500 if in the first 4 lines, else 500
au CursorMovedI * call ModifyTextWidth()   " execute when cursor has moved, use for all files
function! ModifyTextWidth()
    if line('.') < 5               " if line number smaller than 5
        setlocal textwidth=500     " use high tw setting
    else
        setlocal textwidth=72      " Otherwise use normal textwidth
    endif
endfunction
```

If someone plans to implement this, consider replacing the wildcard in `au CursorMovedI *` with a fixed path or file suffix.

Answer (score 4):

A more robust alternative to mxmehl's answer.

If you use `filetype=mail` Vim will highlight headers for you:

[image]

We can use the syntax information to determine if a line is a header, and set the textwidth accordingly.

The syntax name of the headers are `mailHeaderKey`, `mailSubject`, `mailHeaderEmail`, and `mailHeader`. I found this out by looking at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/mail.vim`.

The reason I prefer this solution is that it doesn't depend on arbitrary line numbers, but that it works equally correct for emails with one header and twenty headers.

```
augroup filetypes
    autocmd!

    autocmd FileType mail call s:mail()
augroup end

" Set up ft=mail
fun! s:mail()
    augroup ft_mail
        autocmd!
        autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI *
            \  if index(["mailHeaderKey", "mailSubject", "mailHeaderEmail", "mailHeader"], synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name')) >= 0
            \|     setlocal textwidth=500
            \| else
            \|     setlocal textwidth=72
            \| endif
    augroup end
endfun
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this using autocmds. You could include them in your vimrc, but it is usually better to include them in a filetype, as [explained here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8373/1405).

Then you could use the following:

```
augroup headerTw
   au!
   autocmd InsertEnter <buffer>
            \ if line('.') < 5 |
            \    setl tw=0 |
            \ endif
   autocmd InsertLeave <buffer>
            \ if line('.') < 5 |
            \    setl tw=72 |
            \ endif
augroup END
```

If you prefer to use it without a filetype plugin you will need to replace the `<buffer>` with a file pattern.

The idea is to change the `'textwidth'` when you enter insert mode, and restore it when you leave it.

If you usually navigate in the text while in insert mode (e.g.: using the arrow keys) you could enhance it based on the link mentioned by @Carpetsmoke: [Prevent Vim from breaking up links mid-tag in markdown.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/564/prevent-vim-from-breaking-up-links-mid-tag-in-markdown)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. However, there are a couple workarounds.

1. You could write your header and *then* `:set tw=72`. Since `tw` doesn't apply retroactively to the text already in your buffer,
2. You could type the entire thing with `:set tw=0` and then once you are finished, move to line 4, `:set tw=72`, and `gqG`. Or, if you don't feel like doing that manually, you could macro it or map it. For example, both of these would work:

   ```
   let @r=":set tw=72<cr>4GgqG:set tw=0<cr>"
   nnoremap <silent> <leader>r :set tw=72<cr>4GgqG:set tw=0<cr>
   ```

   ("r" for "reformat")

   You could even set this up to happen automatically when you close vim, assuming that you want it to reformat when you close vim, and that there is a filetype that you use just for emails. For example, if all of your emails had the `.email` extension, you could do:

   ```
   autocommand VimLeavePre *.email set tw=72 | exe "normal! 4GgqG" | w
   ```

   Of course, you'd have to change `*.email` to whatever file extension you actually use. If you use something like `.txt`, I would *not* recommend this, since it will mess with *every* `.txt` file you have.