# Vim highlights long lines for all files

Tags: vimrc, highlight

I have the following setting in my .vimrc for highlight long lines (>79) for python files

```
augroup vimrc_autocmds
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python,rst highlight Excess ctermbg=DarkGrey  guibg=Black
    autocmd FileType python,rst match Excess /\%79v.*/
    autocmd FileType python,rst set nowrap
augroup END
```

By some reason Vim highlights also other files (like .robot).
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might also try to add `set cc=80` to `ftplugin/python.vim` and `ftplugin/rst.vim`.  Much better than relying on `autocmd`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`:help :match`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#:match), it `Define a pattern to highlight in the current window.`. Thus if you open any other buffer (file) on the same *window* it will also display the highlight.

You would be better off by extending the syntax highlight for some languages, as explained at [Vim FAQ 24.11. "How do I add my own syntax extensions to the standard syntax files supplied with Vim?"](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-24.11).

Another option is to use the autocmd events `BufEnter` to set the match and `BufLeave` to clear it.

In any case, you could avoid cluttering your vimrc by using ftplugins, [as explained in here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8373/1405).